# Why can I not blocking main thread in WinRT(Windows Store App)?

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

This question is not about "should I block my main thread" as it is generally a bad idea to block a main/STA/UI thread-for messaging and UI operations, but why WinRT C++/cx doesn't allow any blocking of the main thread compared to iOS, Android, and even C#(await doesn't actually block though).

Is there a fundamental difference in the way Android or iOS block the main thread? Why is WinRT the only platform that doesn't allow any form of blocking synchronization?

EDIT: I'm aware of co-await in VS2015, but due to backward compatibility my company still uses VS2013.

Comment: @RawN UI thread or STA thread in context of COM. In WinRT, UI controls can only interacted via the UI thread.

Comment: Seems to me that if you know it is a bad idea, the real question isn't why Windows doesn't let you do it but why iOS and Android do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big topic, at break-neck speed.  This continues a tradition that started a long time ago in COM.  WinRT inherits about all of the same concepts, it did get cleaned-up considerably.  The fundamental design consideration is that thread-safety is one of the most difficult aspects of library design.  And that any library has classes that are fundamentally thread-unsafe and if the consumer of the library is not aware of it then he'll easily create a nasty bug that is excessively difficult to diagnose.

This is an ugly problem for a company that relies on a closed-source business model and a 1-800 support phone number.  Such phone calls can be *very* unpleasant, threading bugs invariably require telling a programmer "you can't do that, you'll have to rewrite your code".  Rarely an acceptable answer, not at SO either :)

So thread-safety is not treated as an afterthought that the programmer needs to get right by himself.  A WinRT class explicitly specifies whether or not it is thread-safe (the ThreadingModel attribute) and, if it is used in an unsafe way anyway, what should happen to make it thread-safe (the MarshallingBehavior attribute).  Mostly a runtime detail, do note how compiler warning C4451 can even make these attributes produce a compile-time diagnostic.

The "used in an unsafe way anyway" clause is what you are asking about.  WinRT can make a class that is not thread-safe safe by itself but there is *one* detail that it can't figure out by itself.  To make it safe, it needs to know whether the thread that creates an object of the class can support the operating system provided way to make the object safe.  And if the thread doesn't then the OS has to create a thread by itself to give the object a safe home.  Solves the problem but that is pretty inefficient since every method call has to be marshalled.

You have to make a *promise*, cross-your-heart-hope-to-die style.  The operating system can avoid creating a thread if your thread solves the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  Better known as "pumping the message loop" in Windows vernacular.  Something the OS can't figure out by itself since you typically don't start to pump until *after* you created a thread-unsafe object.

And just one more promise you make, you also promise that the consumer doesn't block and stops accepting messages from the message queue.  Blocking is bad, implicit is that worker threads can't continue while the consumer is blocking.  And worse, much worse, blocking is pretty likely to cause deadlock.  The threading problem that's always a significant risk when there are *two* synchronization objects involved.  One that you block on, the other that's hidden inside the OS that is waiting for the call to complete.  Diagnosing a deadlock when you can't see the state of one of the sync objects that caused the deadlock is generally unpleasant.

Emphasis on *promise*, there isn't anything the OS can do if you break the promise and block anyway.  It will let you, and it doesn't necessarily have to be fatal.  It often isn't and doesn't cause anything more than an unresponsive UI.  Different in managed code that runs on the CLR, if it blocks then the CLR will pump.  Mostly works, but can cause some pretty bewildering re-entrancy bugs.  That mechanism doesn't exist in native C++.  Deadlock isn't actually *that* hard to diagnose, but you do have to find the thread back that's waiting for the STA thread to get back to business.  Its stack trace tells the tale.

Do beware of these attributes when you use C++/CX.  Unless you explicitly provide them, you'll create a class that's always considered thread-safe (ThreadingModel = Both, MarshallingType = Standard).  An aspect that is not often actually tested, it will be the client code that ruins that expectation.  Well, you'll get a phone call and you have to give an unpleasant answer :)  Also note that OSX and Android are hardly the only examples of runtime systems that don't provide the WinRT guarantees, the .NET Framework does not either.

Comment: "An aspect that is not often actually tested, it will be the client code that ruins that expectation. Well, you'll get a phone call and you have to give an unpleasant answer" This is the reason that I was considering blocking a UI thread, 99% of our clients can't handle async/concurrency and we wanted to provide a non-async version of our viewer that they do not have to synchronize.

Comment: You can't ignore the "unresponsive UI" problem.  If you don't give them a way to use your code asynchronously then they will give you a call and you have no answer at all.  The use of async/await is in general very well understood by programmers that target WinRT, it is WinRT itself that demands for something as basic as opening a file.

Comment: @legokangpalla: Besides being the standard in the Windows Runtime, asynchronous calls can trivially be wrapped to make them synchronous. There is no easy way to make a synchronous call asynchronous. An asynchronous interface is as such preferable, since it allows your clients to have it both ways.

Comment: @HansPassant If I had any saying in the matter, I would have stuck with the async method, in fact not provide any non-async or provide a non-async with understanding that the user wraps it in an async method. But alas, my predecessor implemented it synchronously with timers etc, and my boss wants the API to be as similar as possible to the iOS platform and told me quite specifically many developers won't be able to use async methods correctly which is somewhat true as many winRT developers I've met in Korea struggle with task based concurreny-or any sort of concurrency.

Comment: @IInspectable Sadly my company assumes that clients will prefer synchronous methods in our library. I can see some C# developers coming to WinRT from WPF background would have no problem with the async/future/await. But management is dead set on synchronous API similar to other mobile platforms.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: because the policy for WinRT apps was "thou shalt not block the UI thread" and the C++ PPL runtime enforces this policy whilst the .NET runtime does not -- look at `ppltasks.h` and search for **prevent Windows Runtime STA threads from blocking the UI**. (Note that although .NET doesn't enforce this policy, it lets you accidentally deadlock yourself instead).

If you have to block the thread, there are ways to do it using Win32 IPC mechanisms (like waiting on an event that will be signaled by your completion handler) but the general guidance is still "don't do that" because it has a poor UX.