# C++CX Why is it possible to explicitly block UI thread by using C# with Windows Runtime Component?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, c++-cx

In my previous question I asked "[Why can I not blocking main thread in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414281/why-can-i-not-blocking-main-thread-in-winrtwindows-store-app)"

Which turned out to be somewhat inaccurate as you can in fact block a UI thread in WinRT, just not in C++CX. The following code will allow you to block UI thread via Windows Runtime Component written in C#.

In you C++CX project, add a new 'C# Windows Runtime Component' project and add this code:

```
    public static bool Await(IAsyncOperation<bool> operation)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Await ENTER \n");
            Task<bool> result = operation.AsTask();
            result.Wait();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Await SUCCESS \n");
            return result.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Await C# Error \n" + e.Message);
        }
        return default(bool);

    }
```

And call it in C++ code like this:

```
 bool success = WindowsRuntimeComponent1::AwaitHelper2::Await(fractalAsync());
```

This code when run at UI thread will block the UI thread until the operation is complete without throwing exception. Honestly, it's a bad idea to use this:

- Lack of generic in Windows Runtime Component, IAsyncAction not being covariant, etc means you cannot use it as a template/generic method. ie) Overload it for all the types you are going to use it with.
- Deadlock is real, especially for tasks that uses UI thread.

So the question I want to ask is that how is this possible? Keep in mind that this is NOT C++CLI and based on COM should not allow this kind of behavior.

EDIT: To clarify, if you attempt to do the same thing in C++ using task::wait() on UI thread, it will throw an exception.

```
void UIThreadBlockWithCLI::MainPage::Button_Pressed(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    task<uint64> randomTask = create_task(fractalAsync);
    //This will throw an exception!
    randomTask.wait();



}
```

Comment: C++ just doesn't have the equivalent of async/await.  Microsoft is trying to get it added to the C++ standard (co_await keyword) but the odds that the industry will accept it are not very good.  Basic job of ISO is to make everybody equally unhappy.  So you'll have to fumble it with the concurrency namespace, create_task() is the workhorse.  Afaict you can ab/use the task::wait() function.

Comment: Okay, so you can't and concurrency runtime keeps you honest.  Peter did mention that in your previous question.  Well, look on the bright side, you now have a completely plausible explanation that you cannot do what your supervisor wants you to do and you have to do this the Right Way.  Solves everything you've been fretting about.

Comment: Indeed - my answer in the original question tells you everything you need to know. The C++ library explicitly throws, not the OS. Something like `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` and any signalable object (like an event) will do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not blocking main thread in WinRT(Windows Store App)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414281/why-can-i-not-blocking-main-thread-in-winrtwindows-store-app)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Ah, since it's just the C++ library throwing, UI thread blocking in C# is essentially...allowed? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, the only thing that stops you is the C++ PPL implementation of wait.